# Rope in computer case safe?

Tags: electrical

I have a sound card (sound blaster Z) that I want to install on my motherboard (mobo).  The problem is, that the hole where the screw is supposed to go through is along the side of the mobo and thus I have no way of attaching it to anything.  I can stick it in the mobo (obviously), but there is a lot of room for wiggling it up and down, since the side isn't bolted down.  That seems incredibly unsafe, especially if I have to move my pc at some point.  I have an idea of using a piece of rope to go through two holes in my case, wrapping around a part of the card and to keep my sound card (mostly) fixed in place this way.

Now the problem is, rope is quite prone to catching fire, and I would prefer no fire in my computer.  The rope shouldn't come in contact with any of the hardware itself, but can a dry environment and the general heat from my pc cause the rope to ignite?  If so, I'll have to find another way to safely install my card.  Sorry if this is a silly question..  I've only read an article a few days back where a man managed to cause 30000 volts worth of static electricity, simply by rubbing his synthetic cloths.  (source: http://www.abc.net.au/news/2005-09-16/man-builds-up-30000-volts-of-static-electricity/2104828)

Comment: If the computer gets hot enough to set fire to the rope, you'll have bigger issues to worry about anyway!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about DIY or Home Improvement

Comment: Thank you - even the accepted answer is not the correct way to address the issue. While yes you *can* do that, it isn't the **proper** way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I call zip ties are what I use to secure items in a PC case. It does not get that hot inside the case in general although some components get quite toasty

[image]

Comment: Interesting idea  :D  I actually am already using zip ties to bundle power cables from the psu together.  I didn't think of using those..  These should be safe for use as they were supplied along with the psu.  I'd give you a +1 but I lack reputation to do it I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are missing the screw that would secure your sound blaster card to the case of the computer?

First, I believe that this may not be the appropriate stack exchange site to post this in but since I am qualified, I will answer your question.

**Do not use rope.**

If your case is missing a whole to properly secure your sound card (or any other expansion card for that matter) the proper way would be to get yourself a drill and drill a small pilot hole, enough so that a computer screw will catch.

The computer case is aluminum so this will require minimal effort and you need to use a screw to keep the card from moving.

Other issues from any other solution: You have invested money into your computer, by not using a screw to properly secure anything within the case can lead to a short and cause serious damage to any number of components within your computer.

**EDIT:** As *HenryJackson* has indicated, remove all components from the computer before drilling to avoid any shavings coming loose and falling within the case.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure where to place my question.  Since this sub forum seemed like a 'do-it-yourself' kind of place, I figured my question would fit in here best.  My apologies anyway.  Any particular reason why you wouldn't use a rope?  I'm not sure I like the idea of drilling in my computer case, especially since I don't have special equipment to do it.  It's very easy to drill too big a hole and leave a mark on my case.

Comment: Using rope in a computer is just not acceptable. You do not require special equipment. An electric drill and a small drill bit will do just fine. Place your card in your computer, use a felt marker to make a dot where the screw should be and then remove the card and drill the pilot hole.

Comment: I would not recommend drilling a hole in the case without first removing **all** of the components, including the motherboard. Drilling through the metal will create tons of slivers of metal that will go everywhere and may well short out the motherboard or something else.

Comment: @HenryJackson - excellent point, will update my answer. SR